# create df form list comprehension within loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have to the following code to create df from a list comprehension within a loop. However, the output is not as I desire.

I would like to create a new column for each group in the list. In this example, 3 groups implies 3 columns.

Input:

```
t = [x * .001 for x in range(2)]
l = [[10, 2, 40], [20, 4, 80], [30, 6, 160]]
tmp = pd.DataFrame([], dtype=object)
    
for i in range(len(l)):
        l1 = [l[i][1]*l[i][0]*l[i][2]*t[j]  for j in range(len(t))]
        tmp = tmp.append(l1, ignore_index=False)
```

Output:

```
l = [[10, 2, 40], [20, 4, 80], [30, 6, 160]]

tmp=
          0
    0   0.0
    1   0.8
    0   0.0
    1   6.4
    0   0.0
    1  28.8
```

Desired Output:

```
0.0  0.0  0.0
0.8  6.4  28.8
```

How can I get the above desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can create lists and then call `DataFrame` cosntructor for improve performance:

```
t=[x * .001 for x in range(2)]
l=[[10,2,40],[20,4,80],[30,6,160]]

tmp = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    l1 = [l[i][1]*l[i][0]*l[i][2]*t[j]  for j in range(len(t))]
    print (l1)
    mp.append(l1)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, dtype=object).T
print (df)
     0    1     2
0    0    0     0
1  0.8  6.4  28.8
```

If need use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
t=[x * .001 for x in range(2)]
l=[[10,2,40],[20,4,80],[30,6,160]]
tmp = pd.DataFrame([], dtype=object)
    
for i in range(len(l)):
        l1 = [l[i][1]*l[i][0]*l[i][2]*t[j]  for j in range(len(t))]
        print (l1)
        tmp=tmp.append([l1])
        
df = tmp.T
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
print (df)
     0    1     2
0  0.0  0.0   0.0
1  0.8  6.4  28.8
```

Comment: To the rescue yet again! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `concat` instead of `append`:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    l1 = [l[i][1]*l[i][0]*l[i][2]*t[j]  for j in range(len(t))]
    l1 = pd.DataFrame(l1)
    tmp = pd.concat([tmp,l1], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to make your code a little bit cleaner and increase its readability, I suggest to use double list comprehension in combination with [`numpy.prod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) and [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) funcitons.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t = [x * .001 for x in range(2)]
l = [[10, 2, 40], [20, 4, 80], [30, 6, 160]]
tmp = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(
        [
            np.prod(np.array(i)) * j
            for j in t
            for i in l
        ]
    ).reshape(len(t), len(l))
)
```

The result looks like this:

```
>>> print(tmp)
     0    1     2
0  0.0  0.0   0.0
1  0.8  6.4  28.8
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative suggestion!